# ENOTFOUND registry.yarnpkg.com error while running yarn install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Usually I run `yarn install` command, it works fine without any issues. But now, while running with same command I'm facing below error:

> Error an unexpected error occurred, 
> "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@babel/core/-/core-7.9.0.tgz" get
> addrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.yarnpkg.com

I have checked in both windows and Mac the same error is occurring.

Comment: I ran to the same problem when my internet went down, FYI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade `yarn` (just in case it's not), then delete `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`. Try running `yarn install` again.